# Sort by name, but ignore quotes?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anyway to sort a column by name, and ignore the quotes that being some items?

For example:

**"This is cool"**

Another article

Article 2

Hello

Would sort as:

**Another article**

Article 2

Hello

"This is cool"

The quotes are already in the database...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM title);
```

Comment: This will be slow on large datasets!

Comment: For more complicated requirements, another option is to plan the table in advance to include a dedicated column for sorting to hold a preprocessed version of the value. For example, storing `name="Dr. Strange Love"` and `name_sort="Love, Strage, Dr."`

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what language you are using. In MS SQL, I use the REPLACE command. So if I have a table, users, with a column first name that I am sorting by, I do this which strips all the double quotes out of the string:

```
SELECT     *
FROM         dbo.Users
ORDER BY REPLACE(firstName, '"', '')
```

Comment: REPLACE will remove all the quotes from the name.

Comment: You're right. But it only removes it when sorting, not from the data itself. It seems that kylex just wants to sort everything without quotes. so this will sort things like:

Ar"ticle 3

Bad example, but that's all I can think of right now. Either way, since it is not affecting the data returned, I don't think there will be a problem.

Comment: But doesn't it affect the sort order in some way?

Comment: It does affect the sort order, but only for items that have double quotes in them ("). So any names that don't have double quotes will be ordered normally, and any names that have quotes in them will be stripped and ordered accordingly. So I guess it would be like: Normal Ordered Names: Article "2, Article 1 Stripped Quote Order Article 1, Article "2. So basically it modifies the order for what he needs, which is ordering without quotes. If he wanted to just ignore the quote if it was at the start, then this would not work. Sorry about the mess. It's hard for me to type without formatting opts

Comment: I tried this. It worked like a charm. It didn't remove quotes from the data I wanted to display, but it did essentially ignore the quotes when sorting. So the word ANSWER shows up before "AWSOME".

Answer (score 3):

A trick that may be acceptable, and faster than TRIM() or REPLACE() based solution is to focus only on the first character being a quote (or by extension a non alphanumeric character).

```
ORDER BY CASE LEFT(myCol, 1) 
      WHEN '"' THEN REPLACE(myCol, '"', '')
      ELSE myCol
    END CASE
```

In general, for bigger dataset, this kind of processing should be done at load time, for example with the addition of columns for querying purposes as opposed to columns for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
 FROM table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN len(col) >= 2
              THEN REPLACE(LEFT(COL, 1), '"', '') 
                 + RIGHT(LEFT(col, LEN(col)-1), LEN(LEFT(col, LEN(col)-1))-1) 
                 + REPLACE(RIGHT(col, 1), '"', '')
              ELSE col
         END
```

in the `ORDER BY`, I eliminate double quotes by replacing it 'within' 1st & last characters by ''. Of course it's only valid when col length >= 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM myTable
ORDER BY replace(name, '"', '')
```